# Vertical center align for multiple page sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Background:**

I am trying to create an interactive lesson. Each lesson is a single page that you scroll down to get to each section (I call them cards).

**Ideal scenario**

I want each section (card) to be full screen with the content vertically centred... like this:

[image]

**My Code**

I am loading each card (section) from a database... it has a title, the content and a file-path for the image on the right.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background:#eaeaec">

    <?php foreach ($cards as $card) : ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div style=" position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <h1>
                    <?php echo $card->card_title; ?>
                    <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
                </h1>

                <?php echo $card->card_content; ?>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="<?php echo $card->card_file_path; ?>" alt="" style="width:100% !important">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

**Problem:**

You can see the in-line CSS which I have tried. This does actually work great... for a single card... but when I add another card all the content gets centred on top of the first card!

[image]

**Question:**

How can I get each section to be the exact height of the window with the card content vertically aligned to that section.

**EDIT 1: Changing my css to position:relative has the following result...**

[image]

Comment: setting the position to relative on the cards didn't work?

Comment: It seems to breaks things more... I will edit my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: Try to avoid using inline styles.

I would suggest to use flexbox:

```
.container {
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Wo..hey, now that's jazzy, works like a dream! And thanks for the tip (although this is some rough and ready prototyping on my part we use SCSS in production)!

Comment: That's good, if you don't have autoprefixer, make sure you add vendor prefixes. for display: flex,